# PyQt : Linking buttons to functions in my program

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

So lets say i have this ui that has 2 empty text spots to fill and a 'Run' button.

I want to make it that the 2 empty text spots go to some values in the program and the run button will basically run the python 'Main' program  ...

how can i do that ?

Comment: Follow the following example code, but use the getText() method to fetch the text from your text boxes. https://pythonspot.com/en/pyqt4-textbox/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PyQt5 the QWidgets module provides a set of UI elements to create classic desktop-style user interfaces. Widgets can display data and status information, receive user input, and provide a container for other widgets that should be grouped together. A widget that is not embedded in a parent widget is called a window.A parent widget containing various child widgets.So first you start to write a code for your window as

```
window=QtWidgets.QWidget()
```

(The QWidget class is the base class of all user interface objects).Once your window is created you need to set a layout for your UI window. There are many classes for layouts in Qt but most common are `QVBoxLayout`(to line up widgets vertically.) and `QHBoxLayout`(to line up widgets horizontally.) and many a times they both are used to make a custom layout. Now create your `QVBoxLayout` as

```
vbox=QWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
```

(note here that vbox is just a variable name).The next thing is to place widgets inside the window which can be done as

```
text_1=QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
text_2=QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
run_btn=QtWidgets.QPushButton("run")
text_3=QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
```

Note that in `QPushButton` we can give the name of the button as its argument(ex-`run` in this case). Now is the time for events and signals.
To connect the PushButton to a function , we write `btn.clicked.connect(function_name)` here `btn` is our PushButton.Note here that the function_name is without parenthesis which means that we have not called the function , just connected the button to the function (when the user will click the button the function gets executed).Foramlly this can be written as

```
run_btn=QtWidgets.QPushButton("run")
def main():
    data_1=text_1.text()
    data_2=text_2.text()
    text_3.setText(str(int(data_1)+int(data_2)))
```

Now in our `main` function we first collected the data from `text_1` and `text_2` (there is a `text()` method for `QLineEdit` to get the data from QLineEdit as a `str`).So our `main` function takes the values of both `text_1` and `text_2` and adds them (it will raise an error if the values entered cannot be converted into integers) and sets that value to the `text_3` by `setText()` method.

Now you have to pack the widgets in our `vbox` which we created earlier as

```
vbox.addWidget(text_1)
vbox.addWidget(text_2)
vbox.addWidget(run_btn)
vbox.addWidget(text_3)
```

And now set the layout of our window as

```
window.setLayout(vbox)
```

And to show the window as

```
window.show()
```

By now one thing is missing and that's the line

```
app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

This line is necessary as every PyQt5 application must create an application object. The `sys.argv` parameter is a list of arguments from a command line. 
Now we have to create the mainloop of the application. The event handling starts from this point. The `app.exec_()` method runs our application and then provide a clean exit.

Now putting all together :

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window=QtWidgets.QWidget()
vbox=QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
text_1=QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
text_2=QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
run_btn=QtWidgets.QPushButton("run")
text_3=QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
def main():
    data_1=text_1.text()
    data_2=text_2.text()
    text_3.setText(str(int(data_1)+int(data_2)))
run_btn.clicked.connect(main)
vbox.addWidget(text_1)
vbox.addWidget(text_2)
vbox.addWidget(run_btn)
vbox.addWidget(text_3)
window.setLayout(vbox)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This will make a UI window like this :

[image]

Hope it helps.
Please do comment in case of some problem .
Happy coding!

Comment: can you explain what u wrote here ? im really bad at coding ... i have no idea what u wrote

Comment: Dear @ItayKatsnelson I have edited my code to a well explained answer please do comment in case of any difficulty :)

Comment: Thanks so much it helped me alot but i just realized im on PyQt4 .. is there any diffrence or i just should install the PyQt5 and follow your code ? thanks so much !

Comment: There is a difference between PyQt5 and PyQt4 and if you are a beginner you must start with PyQt5

Comment: @Tarpaeya ok i understood the code u wrote i just understand what text 3 does and the 3rd line in main with text 3 ...  just want the run button to run my main program/file and the other 2 texts to go in arguments ...how can u do that with what u wrote here?

Comment: you don't need to pass the two text boxes as argument to main just make the two text box global and it will work , you can also post your code to make your question clear

Comment: ok.. and what about running the program ? is there an option in python running it with a command ?

Comment: right now the run btn takes this main def ... i want it to run something .. how do i do that ?

Comment: i want the run to run the python program .. instead of clicking like on the run button on the python interpreter .... you get me ?

Comment: could you post your code , or give me some more hint ..., in case you can also call a function in the shell as >>>main() ;

Comment: i took the web crawler from here : https://github.com/buckyroberts/Spider
I want to 2 text boxes to go to main.py and go to 'PROJECT_NAME' and 'HOMEPAGE' and then after u press run it will run the main.py..

Comment: @ItayKatsnelson The method is same as  i explained here , If you found my answer useful then please accept/upvote it :)

Comment: how is it the same .. ? what does text 3 do ? how can i access whats in text1 and text 2 ? how can i do the run button to close after i click on it ? I dont need the text 3 func in my ui and i want to run button def to get the info in text 1 and text 2 into some variables for example D1,D2 .. how ?

Comment: @ItayKatsnelson you can access text_1 and text_2 via text() method , text_3 is just an example for demonstration , then connect the run button as shown above

Comment: but i cant use the text_1.text() outside the run button def

Comment: @ItayKatsnelson please do clarify what you want to say that you can't use text_1.text() outside the run button, what is stopping you to do so

Comment: lets say i run the program u sent me and i try to print text_1.text() at the end to see what i got and it tells me 'syntax error' when i print data_1 which is data_1 = text_1.text() ...

Comment: data_1 is a local variable , so you cannot access it outside the function , but you can use text_2.text() anywhere after declaring text_1 as a QLineEdit()

Comment: I still cant .... can you add to the previous code u wrote a print to see whats in it .. I still get syntax error and i still cant move whats in text_1 to other variables.. am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: can you help me on how to handle and work with the variables?>

Comment: @ItayKatsnelson first make basic GUI using python like a music player or a calculator then make something interesting like a spider , then you will be able do all the stuff on your own , for help please show what have you done till now .